# Python - Splitting a single csv cell into multiple cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with only one column, an example of a cell is:

```
"What is the capital of France?1)Lille 2)Paris OK3)Nice"
```

I am trying to divide each sentence by separating the statement from all the individual possible answers. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by regex - `\d+` is for one or more numbers and `\)` is escaped `)`:

```
df1 = df['col'].str.split('\d+\)', expand=True)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[
        "What is the capital of France?1)Lille 2)Paris OK3)Nice",
        "What is the capital of Slovakia?1)Bratislava OK 2)Zilina3)Praha"]})


df1 = df['col'].str.split('\d+\)', expand=True)
df1.columns = ['Question','No1','No2','No3']
print (df1)
                           Question             No1       No2    No3
0    What is the capital of France?          Lille   Paris OK   Nice
1  What is the capital of Slovakia?  Bratislava OK     Zilina  Praha
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split()` with this pattern:

```
import re

a = "What is the capital of France?1)Lille 2)Paris OK3)Nice"
answers = re.split(r'\d+\)', a)
print(answers)
```

Output:

```
['What is the capital of France?', 'Lille ', 'Paris OK', 'Nice']
```

And of course, you can adapt this solution to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import re

txt = re.split("[0-9]+\)",txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, you will need to figure out getting your csv string to this, and the re.split() may need modified but should work. :

```
csv_string = "What is the capital of France?1)Lille 2)Paris OK3)Nice"
csv_split = re.split('\d\)', csv_string)
question = csv_split[0]
options = []
for option in csv_split[1:]:
    options.append(option)
return options
```

Comment: I validated this works in python3 in my shell. Enjoy!